# get size of many files at once

Tags: linux, bash

I've found that I can print a list a directories total size with

```
du -sb myDirectory
```

Is there anyway I can apply this same command to an array of directories du -sb (myDirectory yourDirectory hisDirectory)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just list the dirs

```
du -sb myDirectory yourDirectory hisDirectory
```

Note how the man page says:

```
du [OPTION]... [FILE]...
```

That's what the `[FILE]...` means.

If you want to examine all the directories in the current directory

```
du -sb */
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
du -sb {myDirectory,yourDirectory,hisDirectory}
```

Comment: @thomas, this is bash [brace expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Brace-Expansion)

Comment: @thomas See `glenn jackman`'s comment. There is no real difference between this and a space separated list (assuming no directories have spaces, in which case make sure to quote/escape in both syntaxes), though I've always found this syntax simpler.

Comment: Why braces? There's no reason to use braces here. It obscures the fact that `du` accepts multiple directory names as arguments. A space-separated list is the straightforward way to pass multiple arguments.

Comment: @JohnKugelman When is there ever a `reason` to use or not use brace expansion when passing some simple list of arguments? Just used it here as a matter of preference.

Comment: @BroSlow brace expansion is useful when you combine them with strings or other brace expansions, like `echo /home/*/{Pictures,Documents}` to list all user's Picture and Documents directories, or `echo 192.168.{1..256}.{1..256}` to list all ips.

Comment: It's extremely unusual, and there's no reason for it. I have never seen anybody write a list of arguments this way. To me, it misleadingly suggests that shells have some notion of "lists" and that there's a special syntax for them. They don't, and there is not. Bash does have arrays, but there is no syntax for writing an array inline. Or, rather, the syntax is merely a space-separated list of words.

Comment: @JohnKugelman Fair enough. Just went with the one I would usually use for the quick answer (to me it does add some conciseness to complicated commands with lots of flag options and arguments, though suppose someone might mistake it for an array). Anyway, should have probably written both.

Comment: @thatotherguy True, but just meant in cases where both syntaxes can be used.

Comment: @BroSlow Those are both cases where both syntaxes can be used. Once's just significantly more concise.

Answer (score 0):

Specify everything including the sub-directories with:

```
du -sb */*
```